# Where are the Django controllers?

Tags: html, django, forms, view

I'm new to Django and I just got introduced to a new code base.  Everyone else that I'm working with is also new to the code base.

There is a drop down form that requires you to select a "Region". Once a region is selected, another drop down form pops up with a lot of "plots" for that specific region.  However I cannot seem to find the code that is controlling the page.

The specific part of the template I am talking about is this:

```
<select class="form-control">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select a Region</option>
    {% for region in regions %}
        <option value="{{ region.id }}">{{ region.name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

I don't know where the "regions" are coming from.

Comment: Check the javascript included in the template.

Comment: Thanks! It was in an external .js

Answer (score 1):

So I am somewhat confused regarding what you're looking for here. Are you trying to locate the parcel code coming from Python or the JavaScript/Ajax request that is potentially firing in the drop downs? Sounds to me like an Ajax request is being made once a user selects from the first drop down.

My recommendation is to open Dev Tools-(F12) and view the JS source files. Try to locate the snippet of code that is dealing with the drop downs and set some break points so you can step through the code to see what's actually happening one line at a time. Hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks that did help.  Seetting break points is a good idea because Im also new to javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The second drop-down is probably being generated by Javascript. In the template for that page check the Javascript files being included. You can also do a global search in your codebase for `plotInformation`